# Integrate webjob and botframework c#

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs-triggered, botframework

I have created a bot using Microsoft bot framework V4(c#) and a webjob which will be triggered every day.
I want my bot to know that this webjob was triggered and I have no idea how to do that.

Is there a sample I can follow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into [Proactive Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). I don't know what type of webjob you are using, but you can implement the trigger however you wish. Either with the bot polling the webjob or having it call an endpoint on the bot. Please see a dotnet sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages), which does the latter of those two routes (calls another endpoint on the bot). The essence of the proactive message is that it needs to have a reference to a conversation.